# unable to show custom post, due to permalink rewrite on the front end

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am having an issue about rewriting the permalink url for the custom post type in the front end. If I set "rewrite" option of custom post type it starts working, but the url is old fashioned query string.

I have checked out many forums, but nothing have solved my problem. The post type options  are

```
$options = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,

        //'rewrite'              => array('slug' => $name, 'with_front' => true),
        'rewrite'            => false, 
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => NULL,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
      );
```

The root cause of the problem may be the rewrite rules that I have added. I want to include these rules as well and will like to show the custom post type on the front end as well, correctly resulting in 404.

```
        add_rewrite_tag('%edit%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^edit/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&table=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&process=edit','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%view%','([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule('^view/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&table=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%delete%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^delete/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&table=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&process=delete','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%show%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^show/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&table=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]&process=delete','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%coach%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^coach/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&id=$matches[1]','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%athlete%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^athlete/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&id=$matches[1]','top');

    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont have any cache plugins hindering you here.

Try Deleting your .htaccess file
BUT NOT BEFORE MAKING A BACKUP OF IT!

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your time and help. I have resolved the issue. I  have changed the add_action('init') to add_action('wp') for custom rewrite rules and it stopped conflicting with permalinks rewrite rule. I know I haven't mention the add_action code, that was the missing key for me :), thanks again.